# Can a limit cycle be stable and unstable and the same time?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I’m wondering about the possibility of a system that has a limit cycle whose stability only depends on the initial conditions, i.e., the limit cycle can 
be stable, semi stable and unstable at the same time for a fixed a set of parameters, varying just the initial conditions. Is it possible to exist? There is any suitable theorem to show this (non) existence?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but of course a system can have many different limit cycles at the same time. The usual examples in the plane are of the form $\dot r = f(r)$, $\dot\theta = 1$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: What I wanna know is whether the same limit cycle can be stable, semi stable and unstable in the same time fixed a set of parameters, varying just the initial conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that’s not possible for more or less the same reason that a number cannot be positive and negative at the same time.

Stability of a limit cycle is not a property of a trajectory, and thus of initial conditions, but a property of the dynamical system or the limit cycle, respectively.
More specifically, a limit cycle is stable if all trajectories in some neighbourhood converge to it.
The definitions of unstable vary, but all of them involve that in any neighbourhood, there is a trajectory diverging from it.
Thus the definitions are contradictory and thus cannot both be fulfilled at the same time.

The closest you can get is a limit cycle that is only attracting trajectories from one of its sides, i.e., where the limit cycle is a saddle, e.g.:
$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\dot{r} &= (r-1)^2,\\
\dot{θ} &= 1,
\end{alignat}$$
in polar coordinates.
The limit cycle is at $r=1$.
All trajectories starting with $r<1$ will converge to it.
All trajectories starting with $r>1$ will diverge from it.

Comment: By the way, partially what OP asks is possible. If you pick a limit cycle $\gamma$ and consider restriction of system on $W^s_{\gamma}$, then the limit cycle $\gamma$ would be stable; for restriction on $W^u_{\gamma}$ it's purely unstable.